# Test availablity of WCF URL

Tags: c#, wcf, testing, configuration

I am trying to test the availablity of **WCF** service as a part of a tool.
Is it possible or do I have to call a method inside that **WCF** to really test that?
I have tried `client.downloadurl(wcfurl)` but it is failing.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

To test the existence of a WCF service all you need to do is enter the url of the service into a browser:

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/yourservice.svc
```

You should be able to make the same http request in code and check the response. If it's OK then the service exists.

This doesn't check the methods on the service though.

Comment: Do all services support GET? Also, the OP didn't specify HTTP only.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I know the OP didn't specify HTTP only. I was pointing out that this is one way to check if the service exists.

Comment: It is a way to check if an HTTP service exists, assuming that service supports GET.

Answer (score 2):

Create a HTTP request using the URL of your service. Don't forget to set the timeout. The response code 200 means it is all OK

Answer (score 0):

I would try this tool from microsoft.
They provide you this, simply launch the tool and you will see the available methods as exposed on your IService. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx

You can provide the IService code for feedback.